# Dialog at full screen (or with trasparent background)

Tags: android, alert, android-alertdialog

i've tried a lot...
nothig...
i create this thema

```
    <style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <!-- Fill the screen -->
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>

        <!-- No backgrounds, titles or window float -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>      

        <!-- Just to prove it's working -->
        <item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>
    </style>
```

`<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>` -> don't work (i see the red backgroun from ff0000)

same this

```
 final AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,Android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

and

```
 helpDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

how to get a trasnaprent background?
this is a screen (Imagine the part in gray at full screen or trasparent, not with margin)
[Link to preview](https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/u/0/?ui=2&ik=1a36c9a6d3&view=att&th=14053ab3af773c0d&attid=0.1&disp=inline&realattid=1442623760697917440-local0&safe=1&zw&saduie=AG9B_P8w__a_dNAWRfM8tCdsULoJ&sadet=1375796294274&sads=N7Rd1FeIOmzknvSQ7z5tnKrfMKM)

Answer (score 3):

try this , will show full screen loading dialog with transparent background

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Wallpapers.this);
dialog = new Dialog(context);
               dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
               dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
               dialog.setCancelable(false);
               dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
               dialog.show();
```

create xml layout in (res/layout/dialog.xml) and put this code inside it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ProgressBar>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your dialog to be transparent, use this:

**color.xml**

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

**Layout:**

```
android:background="@color/transparent"
```

For pop-up full screen use this:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated

showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY,width , height );
```

For Dialog use this:

```
 getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

Cheers

Comment: dn't work...
First make black the background
Second set 3, blackscreen foreground to the layout, and gray margin of the dialog